# iOS8 - BLE wake up app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Is it possible to wake up the iOS app at the exact time (or after some delay) and communicate with peripheral?  My goal is to set an alarm and communicate with peripheral when it's time to ring.
The only solution that I can guessed is to send a remote (push) notification at that time which will wake up the app and then it can communicate with BLE device. But that way is not acceptable because there are no guarantee that the push will be delivered at the exact time or will be delivered at all.
So is it possible to awake the app at the exact time which uses CoreBluetooth?

Comment: Its probably worth a shot at trying to send a local notification scheduled for that time, one with no alert text, but a content-available flag. No idea if it would work but its worth a few minutes to test.

Comment: Actually currently the alarm already works via local notifications, but thing is that we can't wake up the app with local notifications, but only with remote (push) notifications

Comment: You can schedule local notifications, but you're still not very clear when you want to wake up. What's "ringing"? Give more details.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I meant following. User opens the app and sets the time when he wants to wake up. When he sets the time, it's basically scheduling a local notification with alert text and some sound, which will fire at the user set time.

Comment: Please read my question one more time. As I wrote I know about solution with push notifications,  but in my case I can't use that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible given your restrictions. You can't wake up an app that is backgrounded anytime you want. The only thing remotely close to this is if the BLE peripheral was an iBeacon that the app was region monitoring for, and when you entered the region your app would be awoken with a `didEnterRegion` event. In your case, it doesn't sound like it's an iBeacon and it sounds like it'll be nearby the entire time.

You simply can't wake up an iOS app *exactly when you want to.*

Answer (score 0):

You can sent a local notification to trigger at a specific time using the `fireDate` property. That said, it will only trigger the local notification. You can't kick off background search for a BTLE peripheral as a result of a local (or push) notification. The user would have to launch your app.

A BTLE peripheral can be searched for in the background, but if your app isn't running in the background, that obviously won't work. If your peripheral happens to be an iBeacon, iOS will bring your app to life even if it's not running in the background if you enter that iBeacon's range. You can use a `CLBeaconRegion` to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 0):

[Core Bluetooth now supports background restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW9). It takes a little work to get right though. If iOS terminates your app because of memory pressure, it will attempt to restore your app in the background when it detects a connection attempt, including any services and characteristics you were advertising.

Firstly, you need to set `UIBackgroundModes` in your info.plist file to `bluetooth-peripheral`

Then you need to give your CBPeripheralManager a unique identifier (I do this in `application:didFinishLaunching:withOptions` `AppDelegate.m`):

```
 myCentralManager =
        [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) options:@{ CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:@"myCentralManagerIdentifier" }];
```

Then you need to implement the peripheral restoration delegate method:

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral
         willRestoreState:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSArray *services = dict[CBPeripheralManagerRestoredStateServicesKey];

    // Loop through services
    for (CBMutableService *service in services) {

        // Then characteristics
        for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {

            // Then any centrals that were subscribed
            for (CBCentral* central in characteristic.subscribedCentrals) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

At this point your `CBPerpheralManager` is advertising again, so be careful about overwriting the characteristics again if you're saving them into properties.

You can simulate a memory termination by invoking:

```
kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
```

Comment: does this also survive device restarts?

Comment: Nope unfortunately not, because iOS doesn't automatically start advertising/scanning for your app on restart. Same with if you force quit from the App Switcher.